# Will a BroadcastReceiver be unregistered if activity closes

Tags: android

I register a Broadcastreceiver in an Activity in its onCreate.

```
registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
```

If a User closes the application by pressing the back button, the activity should be destroyed.

If I don't unregister the broadcastreceiver and the user starts the activity once again, does the old broadcastreceiver still exists? Do I have to re-register it?

I know, I should unregister the receiver in the onDestroy()-method but I want to know what happens in the lifecircle if I don't unregister the broadcastreceiver. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Will a BroadcastReceiver be unregistered if activity closes??
```

The answer is No..

If you dynamically register receiver in Activity You need to unregister it in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` of the `Activity` otherwise it will throw `IntentReceiverLeakedException`